# C++ cout an array overwriting the same line

Tags: c++

I made a simple Turing machine using C++ it reads the input from .txt file and then cout's the output in the terminal. The problem is every time the char moves it prints it on the next line, what I want is to cout the output on the same line, so it just overwrites. Yes I tried to use "\r", but what it does it just only print the first char instead of the whole array

```
        for (int j = 0; j < rule; j++)
    {
        cout << tape[j];
        //Sleep(1);
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: "Yes I tried to use "\r", but what it does it just only print the first char instead of the whole array" Show what you tried. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://ideone.com/yoNVNI this is the whole code

Comment: Thats no [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572545/how-do-i-set-cursor-position-to-beginning-of-line-in-c

Comment: What is the result of `cout << rule`  ???

Comment: It print's out 48

Comment: Your "whole code" does not compile on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
for (int j = 0; j < rule; j++)
{
    std::cout << tape[j] << "\r";   //  \r puts cursor back to the start
    Sleep(1000);  //Sleep takes milliseconds so for 1 second you need 1000
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

\r does not work on all output devices. If you really want to control where you draw on the screen you should look into ncurses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Answer (score 0):

I found that using **System("CLS")** helped me to solve my problem, it clears the terminal screen after cout, but because it's a for loop it prints the array again with new values

```
for (int j = 0; j < rule; j++)
{
     cout << tape[j];
        //Sleep(1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("CLS");
}
return 0;
```